# MySQL group by max value

Tags: sql, mysql

Sample tables (many2many = users has many tickers and tickers has many users):

```
#users
id     relevance
1      10           
2      6           
3      8           
4      3
5      5

#users_tickers
user_id     ticker_id
1           2
1           3
2           4
2           1
2           3
3           2
4           2
...
```

I must select users with max relevance for each ticker - so for each ticker one user with the best relevance.
How would you do that?

Comment: You need to select the user with max relevance or the top n users with max relevance?

Comment: top N users with max relevance. So for each existing ticker I need a users with max relevance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do:

```
SELECT FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_tickers ut ON ut.user_id=u.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT FROM users u1 
    INNER JOIN users_tickers ut1 ON ut1.user_id=u1.id 
    WHERE ut1.ticker_id=ut.ticker_id AND u1.relevance > u.relevance
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this in T-SQL. I am not familiar with MySQL's dialect.

```
SELECT * FROM users AS U
INNER JOIN user_tickers t ON t.user_id = U.user_id
WHERE U.RELEVANCE = (
SELECT MAX(RELEVANCE) FROM users as usub WHERE U.user_id = usub.user_id
)
ORDER BY U.relevance DESC

Produces:
user_id relevance    user_id    ticker_id
1                 10         1        2
1                 10         1        3
3                  8         3        2
2                  6         2        4
2                  6         2        1
2                  6         2        3
4                  3         4        2
```

Comment: You have duplicated ticker_id-s in your result.

Comment: Of course. They are repeated in your sample data. How do we know which ticker_id is the correct one? The user_ticker table represents a many-to-many relationship. user of id 1 has two tickers, user 2 has 3, etc... Do you want just the highest ticker_id values? The lowest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
 SELECT *, 
(SELECT U2.user_id FROM users as U2, users_tickers as UT2 
  WHERE UT2.ticker_id = T1.ticker_id
  AND UT2.user_id = U2.user_id
  ORDER BY U2.relevance
  LIMIT 1) 
FROM  tickers as T1
```

I don't know if this is good code, but I think this is what you're looking for. Last time I did SQL everybody was saying Joins are slow, use subquerys. Don't know if that still applies.

EDIT: I tested it in MySQL with the values you gave (and an added tickers table) and it works.

EDIT: And of course you can change the 'n' users by changing LIMIT 1... to LIMIT n

Comment: This will select tickers not users.

Comment: But this is what you said: "So for each existing ticker I need a users with max relevance." Could you maybe post a sample-results table so we know what it's supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users_tickers LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = users_tickers.user_id WHERE ticker_id = 2 ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This would give you the info you requested for a given ticker. Is this what you are asking for? or a complete list of tickers with its most relevant user?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a fast sql. I did it like this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT id, relevance, ticker_id 
    FROM `users` 
    INNER JOIN users_tickers ON users_tickers.user_id=users.id 
    ORDER BY users.relevance DESC, users.created_at DESC
) AS X 
GROUP BY ticker_id 
ORDER BY relevance DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Still far from optimal :).